# Spring REST service not finding GetMapping and returning HTML

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, servlet-filters, spring-rest

I have a [Spring Boot app](https://github.com/bitbythecron/spring-boot-troubleshooting/tree/no-ssl) that exposes a `v1/data/groceries` endpoint:

```
interface GroceryItemPersistor extends CrudRepository<GroceryItem, Long> {
    @Query('FROM grocery_items WHERE grocery_item_name = :name')
    GroceryItem findByName(@Param('name') String name)

    @Query('FROM grocery_items')
    List<GroceryItem> getAllGroceries()
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping('v1/data/groceries')
class GroceryItemResource {
    @Autowired
    GroceryItemPersistor groceryItemPersistor

    @GetMapping
    List<GroceryItem> getAllGroceries() {
        groceryItemPersistor.getAllGroceries()
    }

    ...
}
```

However when I run the app (see the link's README) and issue the following curl statement:

```
curl -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET http://localhost:9200/v1/data/groceries
```

I see this as the output of the curl:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /error. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Then, back in the terminal where the service is running, I see the following console output in response to the curl command:

```
08:57:39.246 [qtp1939022383-16] WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/error] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
08:57:39.247 [qtp1939022383-16] WARN  o.e.j.server.handler.ErrorHandler - Error page loop /error
```

Two concerns:

- Why am I getting 404?
- This is a RESTful API...why is Spring giving me back HTML?!

Comment: Remove content-type header and check with following url "http://localhost:9200/v1/data/groceries/"

Comment: Thanks @VelNaga (+1) - I tried and those suggestions and same exact result for both (same HTML 404 response for both).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

1. Remove the `@RequestMapping` annotation from the top of the controller;
2. Replace the `@GetMapping` annotation over the `getAllGroceries()` method put to the next annotations:

   ```
   @GetMapping(value = "/v1/data/groceries", produces = "application/json;UTF-8")<br>
   @ResponseBody
   ```

Comment: Thanks @Andrey (+1) - I tried your suggestions but they didn't work (exact same result). I added some Spring warning messages to my original question above if that helps...also please don't forget you can clone my app (GH link is provided at the very top) and should be able to reproduce this exactly. Thanks again!

Comment: @smeeb why your classes are in groovy?

Comment: Thanks @Andrey this is a Groovy web service. Ive built dozens of REST services in Spirng MVC (old Spring) and Spring Boot just uses Spring MVC under the hood. Should be 100% compatible as if I wrote them in Java